# Atomicity of writing in a file with mmap?

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, mmap

One way to modify content of a file is run `mmap` with flag `MAP_SHARED` and then write in memory region returned. For example:

```c
struct data *data;
const int size = sizeof(struct data);
int fd = open("data_file", O_RDWR);
ftruncate(fd, size);
data = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
/* Access to 'data' members */
```

Let's consider I use a journalized filesystem (`ext4` with `data=ordered` or `data=journal`). What precautions I should take in order to allow to recover data from `data_file` after a power outage?

IMO, Linux guarantees that write operations will be ordered but it does not guarantee any atomicity. Therefore, application have to implement a kind of journal in order to recover `data_file` (as most databases do). Do you confirm that?

Comment: A write operation can always be interrupted by a hardware/power failure. Thus their atomicity can only be guaranteed by using a journal or other method implemented in/with software. But a file system could offer some atomicity, e.g. of (block) writes or any writes.

Comment: *Linux guarantees that write operations will be ordered*  Modifying `mmap()`'d memory is not a "write operation".

Comment: @AndrewHenle I realize you have completely right. Kernel is not even able to know in what order modifications were done.

Answer (score 2):

> What precautions I should take in order to allow to recover data from `data_file` after a power outage?

Since there's no way you can guarantee true atomicity of updates to `mmap()`'d memory, you need to do two things:

1. Use a mutex or other synchronization mechanism to protect keep your data in as consistent a state as possible
2. Use [`msync()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/msync.html) to force data to be written to disk after any update.

Note that [since you can't prevent `mmap()` data from being written to disk without an `msync()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146496/how-to-have-a-checkpoint-file-using-mmap-which-is-only-synced-to-disk-manually), this is vulnerable to non-atomic updates to data on disk, although that risk can be minimized if your updates never cross a page boundary.  You'd have to have a failure in the middle of an update to your object, and you'd have to have the OS write that page to disk while in the middle of your transaction.

If you place the mutex or other synchronization object within the `mmap()`'d data itself, I suspect the act of obtaining the mutex will cause an update in the `mmap()`'d memory that would delay any writing of data.  Placing the mutex in the data itself would likely complicate recovery, though as long as you could ensure recovery is single-threaded, that shouldn't be much of a problem to work around if it can't be entirely ignored.

A better solution to this recovery problem would be to not use `mmap()` and explicitly write the data in a way that guarantees an all-or-nothing update, but I suspect that would have significant other impacts on your design.

Comment: Do you think `msync` is atomic? Maybe with `data=journal`, but I think I think it is not atomic with `data=ordered`.

Comment: I think that mutex does not help.

Comment: I think you should re-read Andrew's answer, especially the part that says 'or other synchronization mechanism'.  Also listen to what pretty much everybody told you: the only way to make sure mmap()'s data manipulation is atomic is to enforce it yourself...

Comment: @guilleamodeo Even then, you can't really ensure that `mmap()`'d data is synced to disk atomically.  While it's possible to use `msync()` to force a sync, there's no possible way to prevent an OS-initiated sync from writing inconsistent data.  All you can really do is minimize that window and hope.  It's really a bad design. I suspect that the design in this case is a force-fit.  But it's still a square peg in a round hole.

Comment: @AndrewHenle That is why I have never used mmap() for writing. ;-)

Comment: This question here has an answer that explain how to make sure two processes can access correctly to mmapped data -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258091/when-should-i-use-mmap-for-file-access?rq=1

Comment: @guilleamodeo Let's try to keep problems separated. The current question is not about concurrent accesses.