# mkstemp and hard disk stress

Tags: c, unix

Are temporary files created with `mkstemp` synced to disk?

Here is what I have:

1. Program creates temporary file using `mkstemp` and sends fd to another program.
2. This temporary file is `mmap`-ped by both programs and used heavily (up to 400 MB/sec of writes and 400 MB/sec of reads; up to 60 reads and writes per second).
3. I can't use memfd_create (may not be supported on target devices).
4. Lets also assume (and this is almost true) that I can't create this file on tmpfs (like in /tmp).

What I need is guarantee that such file will not stress hard disk. I can't allow it to be written to disk even if this only happens once every 5 seconds. If I can't get such guarantee, I will look for another way.

Additional info (not important):

I am writing wayland compositor for Android devices. Currently temporary files (wayland surfaces actually) are created on tmpfs. And everything works fine as long as SELinux is not enabled. But if I enable SELinux, it prevents fd's from being transferred from client to compositor. Only solution I currently know is to create temporary files in app's home dir. But if such way is dangerous, I will find another.

Comment: By "sends the fd to another program" do you means sends the *file name* to another program?  Or perhaps *forks* another program that inherits the fd?  Because the meaning of an fd is not in the number itself, and handing it off to an unrelated other program does not provide a means for the receiving program to access the same file.

Comment: fd is transferred via unix domain socket. In this case, another program can use the same file.

Comment: Why not use shared memory?

Comment: sysv shm? It is deprecated. Also my program is wayland compositor for android. I can't change all wayland clients to use shm. They send fd.

Comment: *POSIX* shm.  Which works in terms of file descriptors and `mmap()`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check what it is. But this may only work if no real files are created. If shm_open() creates file under /dev/shm or anywhere, using this shm api will not solve anything.

Comment: Oh, wait. I CAN'T change how wayland clients get fd... I can with LD_PRELOAD maybe... But this is not desirable.

Comment: So it is the *client* that creates the file?

Comment: Yes... Wayland clients create temporary file using mkstemp and send fd to server. All I can change is PATH to directory where temporary files are created (using env variable which is respected by clients). But if I set this path to tmpfs, SELinux prevents fd from being transferred. Again, compositor already works fine if SELinux is not enabled. Also, on android devices its very hard to add new SELinux rules...

Comment: If creating temporary file using mkstemp in persistent memory is (or may be)  dangerous, I'll try to mess with SELinux...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are temporary files created with `mkstemp` synced to disk?

The `mkstemp` function does not impart any special properties to files it opens that would prevent them from being synced to disk.  The filesystem on which they are created might have such a property, but that's independent of file creation.  In particular, files created via `mkstemp()` will persist indefinitely if not removed.

> What I need is guarantee that such file will not stress hard disk. I can't allow it to be written to disk even if this only happens once every 5 seconds. If I can't get such guarantee, I will look for another way.

As far as I am aware, even tmpfs filesystems do not guarantee that their contents will remain locked in memory, as opposed to being paged out.  They are backed by *virtual* memory.  But if the actual file is comparatively small and all its pages are hot, then they are likely to remain in memory only.

With regard to the larger problem,

> everything works fine as long as SELinux is not enabled. But if I
>   enable SELinux, it prevents fd's from being transferred from client to
>   compositor. Only solution I currently know is to create temporary
>   files in app's home dir.

By default, newly-created files inherit the SELinux type of their parent directory.  Your Wayland clients presumably do not have sufficient privilege to modify the SELinux labels of the files they create, but you should be able to administratively create a directory wherever you like with a label conducive to your needs.  For example, you could cause a subdirectory of `/dev/shm` to be created for the purpose (at every boot), and `chcon`ned to have an appropriate label.  If the clients create their temp files there then they should inherit the SELinux type you choose.

Comment: Oki, thanks. I also found this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146496/how-to-have-a-checkpoint-file-using-mmap-which-is-only-synced-to-disk-manually
So it seems there is no way to ensure data is not synced.
Going to experiment with SELinux. On android devices managing SELinux is harder, but chcon is available (at least for rooted devices). Thanks for tips.

Comment: Yay, it works. I took context from my apk's home dir and chconned other dir (on tmpfs) to have same context. Now clients are able to create temporary files in this dir and SELinux doesn't prevent fd's from being transferred to server. Sorry for offtopic.