# Is it okay to use mmap() for 4Kb blocks all over the place or is it better to mmap() my whole file in one go?

Tags: c, performance, mmap

I want to work on a file which is composed of 4Kb blocks.

As things happen, I will write more data and map new parts, unmap parts that I do not need anymore.

Is a `map()` of just 4Kb too small when the total amount of file data to map is around 4Gb total? (i.e. some 1,048,576 individually mapped blocks).

I'm worried that making so many small `mmap()` calls is not going to be efficient in the end, even if they are very well directed to the exact blocks I want to use. At the same time, it may still be better than reading and writing these blocks with `read()`/`write()` each time I change one byte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand it, even a single `mmap()` that covers several contiguous 4kb pages will require the kernel (and the TLB, MMU...) to deal with as many virtual/physical associations as the number of these pages (this is the purpose of memory pages; contiguous virtual pages can be mapped to non-contiguous physical pages).
So, considering the usage of these mapped pages, once set up by a unique or by many `mmap()` calls, there should not be any difference in performances.
But each single call to `mmap()` probably requires some overhead in order to choose the part of virtual address space to use; a single `mmap()` call will just have to choose once a big enough virtual location (it should not be too difficult on a 64-bit system, as stated in other answers) but repeated calls will imply this overhead many times.

So, if I had to deal with this situation on a 64-bit system, I would `mmap()` the entire file at once, using huge-pages in order to reduce the pressure on TLB.
Note that mapping the entire file at once does not imply using the same amount of physical memory right at this moment; virtual/physical memory association will only occur for each single page when it is accessed for the first time.

Comment: Huge pages would cause the system to have to write back megabytes for every byte change?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I don't think so. The synchronisation does not happen after each single byte alteration but is controlled with `msync()` (or at least at `munmap()`).

Comment: I just checked the servers on which the final product would run and they don't have huge pages available anyway. It's 64bit though. Therefore the concept of large memory model is definitely available.

Answer (score 2):

There is no shortage of address space on 64-bit architectures. Unless your code has to work in 32-bit architectures too (rare these days), map the whole file once and avoid the overhead of multiple `mmap` calls and thousands of extra kernel objects. With reading and writing changes, it depends on your desired semantics. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4474496).

Answer (score 2):

On 64-bit systems you should pretty much map the entire file or at least the entire range in one go and let the operating system handle the paging in and out for you. The `mmap` calls do have some overhead themselves. In practice the user address space on x86-64 is something like 128 TiB so you should be able to map say 1 TiB files/ranges without any problems.

Comment: Is there a way to know that limit, the 128Tb you mentioned? Looking at `/proc/meminfo`, I have a virtual memory which says _VmallocTotal: 34,359,738,367 kB_ which is 32Tb.

Comment: @AlexisWilke that's the hard hard architecture limit. The operating systems might limit that... And it is the *per-process* limit. That number tells how much all processes have allocated I believe...

Comment: Okay! I think I found it. In `/proc/cpuinfo` we have the number of bits like so: `address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual` and 48 bits is 256Tb, however, Linux probably only offers the lower half so 128Tb.

Comment: @AlexisWilke yep, and then it already did map some areas near the beginning and the end...